# Open browser-standard colorpicker with javascript without type=color

Tags: javascript, html, browser, color-picker

Does anyone knows a javascript only way to open the browser-standard colorpicker, without using a  html field? so i want a javascript what does exactly the same a a click on the html input color field.
Bart

Comment: What is this browser-standard colorpicker you speak of?

Comment: The colorpicker is built into the browser, and can't be triggered programatically, so triggering it without an input is probably not possible either.

Comment: Hide your element with `display: none` and click it with javascript.

Comment: What do you want to trigger it. I belive modern browsers require you to click on something before you can trigger it to open.

Answer (score 11):

You are going to have to use the input field, you can just hide it off the page. Issue here is the fact that the color dialog requires a click in browsers in order to open up the color dialog. It will not work if you just call click()

```js
document.getElementById("xxx").addEventListener("click", function() {
  document.getElementById("c").focus();
  document.getElementById("c").value = "#FFCC00";
  document.getElementById("c").click();
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  position: absolute;
  left: -10000px;
  top: auto;
  width: 1px;
  height: 1px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<input type="color" id="c" tabindex=-1 class="hidden">
<input type="button" id="xxx" value="Click Me!">
```

Comment: thanks, but in fact, the thing where i want to use it for, is to launch the colorpicker by clicking a bookmark in chrome. At this moment i also added a javascript to a bookmark to launch a div on the page with dimensions in it. The same way i want to add a "show colorpicker" bookmark, this way i can't use a input field hidden anywhere.

Comment: Might be better to actually create an extension.

Comment: this works in chrome/firefox/IE11/safari except edge

Comment: The thing on Safari is that you must focus() it first. A simple click won't open it.

Comment: Currently it only works in Firefox. Other browsers doesn't use a dialog.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a good old "hover-hack" solution that works even in MS Edge:

```
<input type="color" style='opacity:0;width:100px;position:absolute;'/>
<button>clickme</button>
```

then bind `onchange` to the colro element

https://jsfiddle.net/Lnzm0sry/2/

Answer (score 0):

```
 // I’ve been using this component for my projects://

<html>
<script src="https://jsuites.net/v5/jsuites.js"></script>
<script src="https://jsuites.net/v5/jsuites.webcomponents.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://jsuites.net/v5/jsuites.css" type="text/css" />
<jsuites-color value="#009688"></jsuites-color>
<script>
document.querySelector('jsuites-color').addEventListener('onchange', function(e) {
    // Set the font color
    e.target.children[0].style.color = this.value;
    // Show on console
    console.log('New value:' + this.value);
});
</script>
</html>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AwFLF.png)
// https://jsuites.net/docs/color-picker

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).