# <input type="color" /> — open colorpicker with js

Tags: javascript, input

I have got that:

```
<span class="opener">Open</span>
<input type="color" class="btn-invisible" />
```

and I would like to open the colorpicker of that field using JS. I have tried:

```
document.querySelector('span.opener')
  .addEventListener('click', 
    e => document.querySelector('.btn-invisible').focus()
  );
```

But that doesn't open the color picker. If that can be done by JS, how?

Comment: Why `.focus()` instead of `.click()`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Open browser-standard colorpicker with javascript without type=color](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29676017/open-browser-standard-colorpicker-with-javascript-without-type-color)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The color input control requires a click (like a button).

```js
document.querySelector('span.opener')
  .addEventListener('click', 
    e => document.querySelector('.btn-invisible').click()
  );
```

```css
.btn-invisible {
   display: none;
}
```

```html
<span class="opener">Open</span>
<input type="color" class="btn-invisible" />
```

Comment: Haven't known about the `.click()` method on such form elements, but it works like charm, thanks!

Comment: Although it works in Edge if you focus input before click (`.focus()`) and hide it softly (eg. `opacity: 0`). Playground: http://jsbin.com/vejuqif/edit

Answer (score 8):

There's no need for javascript, just wrap a label around the input:

```html
<label>
  Open
  <input type="color" style="display:none">
</label>
```

Comment: I will give it shoot!

Comment: I asked for a JS Solution, so it wouldn't be right to accept a non-JS solution, even if I now like it more than with js ;)

Comment: Yes, I realize that it's not exactly what you asked for but figured it was worth pointing out in any case :). In general it's better to avoid having JS to do unnecessary work. More event listeners = more chance of unintended consequences.

Comment: This is the real way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Add an Id to the color input (you can keep it hidden if you want) then fire a click event with javascript. Click outside the color picker to get the color value.

```js
function show_colorpicker(){
document.getElementById('pick_color').click();
}
function show_color(){ alert(document.getElementById('pick_color').value)
}
```

```html
<input onchange="show_color();" type="color" id="pick_color" name="pick_color" style="display:none" />

<a onclick="show_colorpicker();">Click me!</a>
```